# Javascript reading particular line of text from text file

Tags: javascript, file, text

For a little background: Text prints on screen. the text is a story line. Now, there's lots of different paragraphs that print out, whichever is currently printing is controlled by setting a variable equal to the next string. I'm looking for the best way to store all this text and reference it easy. Would it be best to store it in a text file, and refer to it by finding which numbered bullet point its at? I currently have a long section of code to print it and it seems very tedious to do it this way. Example of current:

```
    storyText = "Text";
    GC.printText(storyText);
    await sleep(5000);
    storyText = "Text";
    GC.printText(storyText);
    await sleep(5000);
    storyText = "Text";
    GC.printText(storyText);
```

Comment: Is it node.js, because you can surely read a file by bytes chunks, something like `fread()` in C or PHP,  any server lang can do this easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understood, but if you put the paragraphs into an array and use a loop with a timeout, it should work (see below). If it's a long story, I'd use a database.

```
const story = [
    "paragraph 1",
    "paragraph 2",
    "paragraph 3",
    "paragraph 4"
];

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function printStory() {
    for(para in story) {
        await sleep(5000);
        console.log(story[para]);
    }
}

printStory();
```

Comment: I didn't think of doing that, great suggestion! I'll try going this route, and havent had any experience with databases so will look into those as well. Thank you very much for the answer, I wasn't sure where to go with this at all but now I have a direction to explore!